# CF memory allocation example

Tags: cocoa, core-foundation

Reading Apple doc on CF memory management, I see an example:

```
static CFStringRef title = NULL;
void SetTitle(CFStringRef newTitle) {
    CFStringRef temp = title;
    title = CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault , newTitle);
    CFRelease(temp);
}
```

It says that release is made using temporary reference in case `newTitle` and `title` are pointing to the same memory location. But I'm not sure if I understand what would happen if it will just release `title` and then create a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `newTitle` and `title` are both pointers and pointers can point to the same memory locations.

So imagine if you had it as

```
static CFStringRef title = NULL;
void SetTitle(CFStringRef newTitle) {
    CFRelease(title);
    title = CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, newTitle);
}
```

which gets rid of the temp variable and looks a lot simpler. That's all well and good.

But what if you then did this

```
SetTitle(title);
```

So when you get into the function, both `newTitle` and `title` are pointing to the same address! So the first line of the function will release `title`; but this is also releasing `newTitle` at the same time (because they're the same!).

So by the time it gets to the second line of the function, the memory where `newTitle` was has gone away. Maybe it was zeroed out. Maybe it's being used to hold the first few chapters of *War and Peace*. We don't know, but we do know that it's definitely no longer what this function was expecting `newTitle` to be and is essentially garbage memory.

So the second line of the function will try to make a copy of garbage memory. If you're very, very, very lucky, your app will crash. But I'm pretty sure that this will ultimately result in undefined behavior so if your computer sets itself on fire and starts singing "God Save The Queen", you have only yourself to blame.

In Apple's version, it's setting aside the original `title` into a temporary variable, creating the copy, and *then* releasing what was the original `title`. This is fine because the copy won't be done on garbage data and your computer remains blissfully not-on-fire.

Win-win.

Comment: Thanks for interesting and funny explanation. My understanding was that CFRelease was just marking object for removal like autorelease. But now I know that once I call `CFRelease` then I should never think that the object is valid.